window function for analysing a string

So when the record has the same VAR, same Group but different SalesPrice: i need to comment it as 'need to define'
i was trying to use window function but cannot succeed with it.
any help is appreciated
thanks a lot in advance
I tried to use window function and adding extra columns but it just does not make any effective result.

select *, case when max(salesprice) over(partition by Var, [Group]) <> MIN(salesprice) over(partition by Var, [Group]) THEN 'need to define' else '' end from yourtable perhaps? This doesn't handle NULLs though

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.v

As suggested by @siggemannen in the comments, you can use the MIN() and MAX() window functions. If the minimum value differs from the maximum value within a group, then flag it :
SELECT *, CASE WHEN MAX(salesprice) OVER (PARTITION BY Var, [Group]) <> MIN(salesprice) OVER (PARTITION BY Var, [Group])
               THEN 'need to define' ELSE '' 
          END AS Comment
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ID

If you are using SQL SERVER 2022+ then use the WINDOW clause to define a window once and reference it multiple times in a query :
SELECT *, CASE WHEN max(salesprice) OVER win <> MIN(salesprice) OVER win
               THEN 'need to define' ELSE '' 
          END 
FROM mytable
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY Var, [Group])
ORDER BY ID


Small clarification - using the window clause syntax does not by itself guarantee that the same pass over the data will be used.  It is based on the over clauses themselves.  The top syntax examine in this answer will also generate a plan with the same property.  Obviously using the window clause can help avoid typos and simplify reading the SQL text to make it easier to maintain, but you can think of the window clause as being macro-expanded into the query plan as if you had typed the full version above.
